# How to redirect without flickering in React using React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm building a SPA with React utilizing React Router and encountered this conceptual issue.

So, this is my App component, which has a React Router.

```
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="appwrap">
        <Jumbotron></Jumbotron>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Router>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Display}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/saved" component={Saved}></Route>
        </Router>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In my Navbar component there are a couple of simple functions redirecting to href, which obviously are causing the page to 'flicker' and refresh. This is what I'm trying to get rid of (the flickering). My Navbar component is right here.

```
class Navbar extends Component {
  redirectToSearch = () => {
    window.location.href = '/'; 
  }
  redirectToSaved = () => {
    window.location.href = '/saved'; 
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="navbar">
          <div className="navbaropt" onClick={this.redirectToSearch.bind(this)}>search</div>
          <div className="navbaropt" onClick={this.redirectToSaved.bind(this)}>saved</div>
      </div>
    );}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution on the following post: [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router).

Replace `window.location.href` with `this.props.navigation.push`

update your functions to below

```
redirectToSearch = () => this.props.navigation.push('/');

redirectToSaved = () => this.props.navigation.push('/saved');
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Sine I'm avoiding <Link> at all cost.

Answer (score 7):

For in-page navigation with React Router you have to use the `Link` element.

```
  <div className="navbar">
      <Link to="/">search</Link>
      <Link to="/saved">saved</Link>
  </div>
```

Read all about it [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: Why would you want to avoid the Link tag?

Comment: I can't even begin to understand what's going on here. There's nothing in your original question that remotely indicates that you do not want to use a Link tag.

Comment: Also, you can save some cycles by binding only once in the constructor as opposed to every render. But you don't even need to bind since you are using arrow functions

Comment: Agree. OP and anyone should just use `Link` instead for best practice.